# What is proper way to call function from onClick so it don't trigger wrong one?

Tags: reactjs, function, onclick

When I click on button then `onClick` triggers correct function, run half through and jumps to other function which is not related to it and run through half of it and jumps back to first function, runs half trough again and drops error

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase is not a function

Interesting part is that I click other button before which triggers this function with `toLowerCase()` and there is no errors.

I dont have any idea whats going on here but so far i was trying to remove few lines to see which line cause it because I dont think that line with `toLowerCase()` realy is the reason. Everything works when I remove lines where is first `this.setState`.

Here is my function: 
( Alerts is used to track where function is at, that how i know
that it run half through only. It never reach `alert("DDD")`.
This function is which is triggered with button `onClick` like it should be )

```
  onSelect = (e) => {
    const data = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    const itemId = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    const itemIdState = !this.state[e.target.getAttribute('data-id')];
    alert("AAA")

    this.setState(state => {  // <--- Somehow problem comes from this setState function
      const newState = {};
      for (const dataId in state) {
        newState[dataId] = dataId === data
      }
      alert("BBB")
      return newState
    });
    alert("CCC")

    this.setState(State => ({
      [itemId]: itemIdState,
    }), function() {
      alert("DDD")
      if(this.state[itemId] === true){
       this.setState({isAnySelected: true})
     }else if(this.state[itemId] === false){
        this.setState({isAnySelected: false})
      }
    })
  }
```

This is other function which is triggered by mistake and is not related to other. It is just returning component which is displayed and when I press on its button then i have this issue.

```
  filterSearch = (id, title, path) => {
    let name = title.toLowerCase()
    let filter = this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase()
    if(name.includes(filter)){
      return <SearchResult key={id} data-id={id} pName={path} onClick={this.onSelect} selected={this.state[id]} />
    }
  }
```

And here is from where `filterSearch` is triggered. Behind `this.props.searchResult` is Redux.

```
    {this.props.searchResult ? this.props.searchResult.map(category =>
      this.filterSearch(category.id, category.title, category.path)
     ) : null
    }
```

Comment: Can you get an example set up in Plunkr or CodeSandbox or wherever?

Comment: never was working before with these kind of pages, i find it hard to make replica there. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what the problem is: in your problematic `this.setState`, you cast everything in your state to a boolean:

```
this.setState(state => {
  const newState = {};
  for (const dataId in state) {
    newState[dataId] = dataId === data
  }
  alert("BBB")
  return newState
});
```

Your `for()` statement ends up comparing `searchValue` to `data` (some kind of ID), which I imagine more often than not will *not* be the case, so `searchValue` ends up getting set to `false`.

And what happens when you try to do `.toLowerCase()` on a Boolean?

[image: toLowerCase doesn't exist on Booleans]

To fix this, consider structuring your state like this:

```
this.state = {
  searchValue: '',
  ids: {},
};
```

Then, replace your problematic `this.setState` with something like this:

```
this.setState((state) => {
  const newIDs = {
    // Create a clone of your current IDs
    ...state.ids,
  };

  Object.keys(newIDs).forEach(key => {
    newIDs[key] = key === data
  });

  alert("BBB")

  return {
    // searchValue will remain untouched
    ...state,
    // Only update your IDs
    ids: newIDs,
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes looks like that but that function where is toLowerCase is triggered before. After that I trigger other function which dont have toLowerCase. Why my previous function care about that state if im not using it anymore ? Confusing. Does that mean it is listening to state all the time ?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about React components is that `render()` gets called many times, even if you don't intend for it. Your first `this.setState()` is probably triggering a re-render. The `.map()` you're using in `render()` to display search results, that calls `this.filterSearch()`, fails because you've updated state and set `searchValue` to a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you wanting to do here?

```
this.setState(state => {
  const newState = {}; // You are initializing an object
  for (const dataId in state) {
    newState[dataId] = dataId === data // You are putting in an array every property of state that is equal to data
  }
  return newState
});
```

So irrevocably, your `this.state.searchValue` property will be changed to something else, which is of boolean type. So toLowerCase being a function for string.prototype, you will get an error.

You should describe what you where aiming to get here.

Comment: By that I'm setting all states to false. I have buttons which works like checkbox, just one can be selected so all states is changed to false and selected button to true.

Comment: So @IAmKale has it right, you should separate your checkbox states from searchValue and put them as an object."..." notation will spread the existing properties in the state, and you will override the ids specifically when declaring them.